# T = {U ⊆ X : U = X or U ∩ V = ∅} is a topology on X.

Tags: general-topology

Prove or disprove the following statement:

Let $X$ be a set, and let $V$ be a proper nonempty subset of $X$. Then $T = \{U \subseteq X : U = X \text{ or } U ∩ V = \varnothing\}$ is a topology on X.

I think it is true statement, and I know we need to show three conditions to show it is topology on $X$:

both the empty set and $X$ are elements of $T$,

any union of elements of $T$ is an element of $T$, and

any intersection of finitely many elements of $T$ is an element of $T$.

But I do not know how can I show it when $T = \{U \subseteq X : U = X \text{ or } U ∩ V = \varnothing\}$.  Any help with that please

also , how about if T = {U ⊆ X : U = X or U ∩ V ≠ ∅} is a topology on X.

I think it is false statement because empty set does not belong to T and also U ∩ V ≠ ∅

Comment: Start from the easier one first. Is $\emptyset$ and $X$ in $T$?

Comment: What is $\tau$?

Comment: T means topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Clearly $\emptyset$ and $X$ are elements of $T$

2) Let $A_n$ be a sequence of sets in $T$ then we want to show that $\bigcup_n A_n \in T$ too.

If $\exists N$ s.t. $A_N=X$ then since $A_n \subseteq X, \forall n$ then $\bigcup _n A_n =X\in T$

If no such $N$ exists, then $A_n \cap V=\emptyset, \forall n$. Thus$$(\bigcup_n A_n) \cap V=\bigcup_n (A_n\cap V)=\bigcup_n \emptyset =\emptyset $$
Therefore, $\bigcup _n A_n \in T$

3) Let $(A_k)^n _{i=1}$ be a finite sequence of sets in $T$ then we want to show that $\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k \in T$.

If $A_k=X, 1\leq k \leq n$ then  $\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k =X\in T$.

Split $A_k$ into $A_{k_1}^{(1)}$ and $A_{k_2}^{(2)}$ where $A_{k_1}^{(1)}$ are all those $A_k$'s s.t. $A_k=X$ and $A_{k_2}^{(2)}$ are the sets that remain.
Thus
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k = \bigcap_{k_1} A_{k_1}^{(1)}\cap \bigcap_{k_2}A_{k_2}^{(2)} =\bigcap_{k_2}A_{k_2}^{(2)}$$

Since all sets $A_{k_2}^{(2)}$ are those sets s.t. $A_k \cap V =\emptyset$ then

$$(\bigcap_{k_2}A_{k_2}^{(2)})\cap V=\bigcap_{k_2}(A_{k_2}^{(2)}\cap V)=\bigcap_{k_2}\emptyset=\emptyset$$

Thus $\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k\in T$

Comment: Btw for the intersection part, the reason why $\bigcap_{k_1}A_{k_1}^{(1)}$ disappears is because it is equal to $X$ and since $A_{k_2}^{(2)}\subseteq X$ then use the fact that if $A\subseteq B$ then $A \cap B = A$

Comment: @Henno Brandsma ,in this question how about V be a proper nonempty subset of X , does it can do anything on the answer since it is arbitrary but fixed.