# prove or disprove on topological space​ of X

Tags: general-topology

prove or disprove on topological space​

a)Let X be a set, and let V be a proper nonempty subset of X. Then T = {U ⊆ X : U = X or U ∩ V = ∅} is a topology on X

[T = {U ⊆ X : U = X or U ∩ V = ∅} is a topology on X.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272294/t-u-%e2%8a%86-x-u-x-or-u-%e2%88%a9-v-%e2%88%85-is-a-topology-on-x) this answers part a but I do not see the answer for part b

b). Let X be a set, and let V be a proper nonempty subset of X. Then T = {U ⊆ X : U = X or U ∩ V ≠ ∅} is a topology on X.

my answer,

T is not topology on X since empty set does not belong to T

is that right and the answer is trivial like that?

Comment: Remove the "and $U\cap V\neq\varnothing$" (which makes no sense) from your answer and you're golden

Comment: More rigorously, suppose $\emptyset \in T$ where $\emptyset \neq X$. Then clearly $\emptyset \cap V = \emptyset \neq \emptyset$. Contradiction.

What if $\emptyset = X$?

Comment: @Malcolm. The hypothesis is that V is non-empty so X is not empty either.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes obviously. But the point was for the author to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

The answer is trivial

Suppose $\phi\in T$ and $\phi\neq X$ , then clearly $\phi\cap V=\phi$ a contradiction.

Now if $\phi= X$, then there is no proper nonempty $V$ of $X$ , so the question makes no sense, hence the question itself demands that $\phi\neq X$.